# Difference between (Mysql,Sql server,Oracle etc..) and Hadoop Big Data Analytics?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, bigdata

What are the Basic differences and features between commonly used databases like (MySQL,SQL Server,Oracle etc...) and Hadoop Big Data Analytics ? Can anyone list in short and not in much detailed format?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a research site. quora might be a good place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc are relational database management systems (RDBMS).  The difference between them is simply the company/organization that owns/maintains them.

Hadoop and the term of big data constitute a change in DB design. Big data platforms and data warehouses focus on decreasing normal form and flattening out relational tables for the purpose of quick retrieval.  RDBMS systems on the other hand try to maximize normal form to decrease storage sizes, increase data integrity, and mitigate writing time for OLTP systems.